# How to get the highlight text from TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I want to extract the text highlighted by the user using the TinyMCE. I have been able to extract the whole text with the TinyMCE API, and even just the paragraph selected with `getNode()`. I thought that `getSel()` would do it but it returns an object and I want the string.

```
var content = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getSel();
console.log(content);
```

Returns:

```
Selection {anchorNode: text, anchorOffset: 259, focusNode: text, focusOffset: 286, isCollapsed: false, …}
```

TinyMCE: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.selection/#getsel

I also found getSelection in JavaScript, however it seems not to work properly in Chrome. Either way I prefer to use the TinyMCE API if it is possible.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the official documentation at [tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.selection/#getcontent](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.selection/#getcontent):

> ```
> // Alerts the currently selected contents
> alert(tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent());
>
> // Alerts the currently selected contents as plain text
> alert(tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent({format: 'text'}));
> ```

You would write your code like this:

```
var content = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
console.log(content);
```

[EDIT]
Or to get the plain-text content:

```
var content = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent({format: 'text'});
console.log(content);
```

Note the difference between `tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent()` and [`tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent).

- `tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent()` - get the HTML or plain-text of the *selected*/highlighted content in the editor/`textarea`.
- `tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()` - get the *entire* content of the editor/`textarea`.

Comment: That's for the whole content. And its what I have now. What I want is just the highlighted text by the user,

Comment: You mean, the *plain*-text in the highlighted text? If so, you can pass `{format: 'text'}` to `tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent()`? And actually, if you have "*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet*" in the content, and user selected the "*dolor sit*" text, then `tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent()` would return *dolor sit*. Note the difference between `tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent()` and `tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()`.

Comment: tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent({format: 'text'});

Comment: Yes, passing `{format: 'text'}` would let you retrieve just the plain-text portion of the highlighted content, which may or may not contain HTML tags. And you're welcome! =)

Comment: how to add this tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent() to a textfield in dialogue box like in link plugin @SallyCJ

Comment: @AmalSebastian I think it's better if you post that as a new question and include a working/testable snippet based on your actual code.